# Building cm-13. for g7102

Tags: cyanogenmod

I started for building cm13
but have issue

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/sam/cm/kernel/samsung/ms013g'
/home/sam/cm/out/host/linux-x86/bin/checkpolicy:  loading policy configuration from /home/sam/cm/out/target/product/ms013g/obj/ETC/sepolicy_intermediates/policy.conf
libsepol.report_failure: neverallow on line 454 of external/sepolicy/system_server.te (or line 12271 of policy.conf) violated by allow system_server dex2oat_exec:file { execute execute_no_trans };
libsepol.report_failure: neverallow on line 399 of external/sepolicy/domain.te (or line 5661 of policy.conf) violated by allow init su_exec:file { execute };
libsepol.report_failure: neverallow on line 399 of external/sepolicy/domain.te (or line 5661 of policy.conf) violated by allow untrusted_app su_exec:file { execute execute_no_trans };
libsepol.report_failure: neverallow on line 399 of external/sepolicy/domain.te (or line 5661 of policy.conf) violated by allow sudaemon su_exec:file { execute };
libsepol.report_failure: neverallow on line 360 of external/sepolicy/domain.te (or line 5622 of policy.conf) violated by allow system_server dalvikcache_data_file:file { write };
libsepol.check_assertions: 5 neverallow failures occurred
Error while expanding policy
make: *** [/home/sam/cm/out/target/product/ms013g/obj/ETC/sepolicy_intermediates/sepolicy] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

Answer (score 0):

I got similar experience with 2 devices like S2 plus and wiko rainbow, the better way is commenting out with # the error's lines appear in the .te files in external/sepolicy, i guess the source still fresh and buggy.